# Action, Func and Predicate delegates - C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, delegates

I'm trying to understand the differences between the `Action<T>, Func<T> and Predicate<T>` delegates as part of my WPF/MVVM learning.

I know `Action<T> and Func<T>` both take zero to one+ parameters, only `Func<T>` returns a value while `Action<T>` don't.

As for `Predicate<T>` - I have no idea.

Therefore, I came up with this following questions:

1. What does `Predicate<T>` do? (Examples welcomed!)
2. If `Action<T>` returns **nothing**, wouldn't it be simpler to just use `void` instead? (Or any other type if it's `Func<T>` we're talking about.)

I'd like you to avoid LINQ/List examples in your questions.
I've seen those already but they just make it more confusing as the code that got me 'interested' in these delegates have nothing to do with it (I think!).
Therefore, I'd like to use a code I'm familiar with to get my answer.

Here it is:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    : this(execute, null)
{
}

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
{
    if (execute == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
{
    return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}

public void Execute(object parameters)
{
    _execute(parameters);
}
}
```

**Note:**
I took out the comments to avoid super-long block of code.
The full code can be found [HERE](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks! :)

P.S: Please don't point me to other questions. I did try to search but I couldn't find anything simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: A `Predicate` must return a boolean. I *will* point you to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710301/what-is-a-predicate-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Predicate<T>` is a delegate that takes a `T` and returns a `bool`.
It's completely equivalent to `Func<T, bool>`.

The difference is that `Predicate<T>` was added in .Net 2.0, whereas all of the `Func<*>` delegates were added in .Net 3.5. (except the ones with >8 parameters, which were added in .Net 4.0)

The LINQ-like methods in `List<T>` (`FindAll()`, `TrueForAll()`, etc) take `Predicate<T>`s.

To answer your second question, `void` cannot be used as a generic parameter.

Comment: I see. I think I understand it better now... To sum it all up, `Predicate<T> where T=int` for example is also equal to `public delegate bool Delegate(int x)` right? (= Predicate has no any special functionality whatsoever...)

Answer (score 1):

> What does Predicate do? (Examples welcomed!)

It must return `boolean`, and used in conditional constructs. It is equivalent ([but not assignable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/665572/649524)) to `Func<T, bool>`. [Predicate is mostly used in List for methods like FindAll and RemoveAll.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4317512/649524)

`Action<T>` vs `Func<T,bool>`

You cant represent a function returning void as `Func<void, T>`. So `Action<T>` is required. `Void` type cannot be used in [generics](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/06/06/forbidden-void-type-in-c/).

Comment: Actually, `Predicate<T>` is not used anywhere in LINQ.

Comment: @SLaks, checked and updated my understanding and answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. In your linked examples, `list.Select(x => x.SomeProperty)` was presented as a possible usage of `Func`. How is `Func` used here? I also couldn't find anything about the usage of `.Select()`...

Comment: `x=> x.SomeProperty` is Example of `Func<T,U>` Where U-> type of x.SomeProperty, and T-> type of x

Answer (score 1):

> What does Predicate do? (Examples welcomed!)

Predicate is a function that takes an argument and returns bool e.g `x > 20`

> If Action returns nothing, wouldn't it be simpler to just use void instead? (Or any other type if it's Func we're talking about.)

Action is defined as delegate that returns void. Here one may argue why there are two kind of delegates, but simply that's the outcome of the design. Another approach is to have `Func` that returns `Unit` that does nothing.

Comment: So, in essence, you could say that `Action`, for example, is a generic delegate for `public delegate void Name(type paramName)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Func<T,bool> and Predicate<T>
```

tends to the same delegate.
But Predicate is Kindof traditional because Predicate was a delegate Type
since from beginning when there was no Func or Action.
If you will see FindAll/Find method of classes like Array ,List
they use Predicate.Predicates return only bool but Func can return any type you specify so bool also comes in that.

Answer (score 0):

A Predicate is a delegate that takes a T and returns a boolean, in essence it's a filtering function. Or that is what you will use it for mostly.

If you use Linq's Where() extension method you will see it receives a Predicate delegate as a parameter, also you can use Predicates to create more intricate filtering methods as Expressions and dynamically combine multiple Predicate delegates with AND or OR conditions between them and so forth.

For example i had a requirement to build a Report page in WPF where the user could dynamically select multiple parameters to customize the Report page's content, and in that case i created Predicates for selected filtering options (datetime intervals, booleans, certain strings that must be contained in selected fields etc.) and then combined the predicates and compiled them into an expression that i later used to filter the collection of data i showed the user.

---

EDIT: Check this - [Why Func<T,bool> instead of Predicate<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665494/why-funct-bool-instead-of-predicatet)

in short : coding guidelines state to not use Predicates anymore and use Func instead

Comment: Actually, all of the LINQ methods take Funcs or Actions.  Predicates have no additional ability to be combined.

Comment: @SLaks yes indeed but a predicate is indeed a Func<T,bool> and in the documentation for the Where extension method you can see that the parameter is refered to as a Predicate - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx

Comment: He's asking about the `Predicate<T>` _type_, which has nothing to do with LINQ.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between Func and Action is simply whether you want the delegate to return a value (use Func) or doesn't (use Action).

Func is probably most commonly used in LINQ - for example in projections:

```
list.Select(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

or filtering:

```
list.Where(x => x.SomeValue == someOtherValue)
```

or key selection:

```
list.Join(otherList, x => x.FirstKey, y => y.SecondKey, ...)
```

`Action` is more commonly used for things like `List<T>`.

`ForEach`: execute the given action for each item in the list.

I use this less often than `Func`, although I do sometimes use the parameterless version for things like `Control.BeginInvoke` and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

`Predicate` is just a special cased `Func<T, bool>` really, introduced before all of the `Func` and most of the `Action` delegates came along. I suspect that if we'd already had `Func` and `Action` in their various guises, `Predicate` wouldn't have been introduced... although it does impart a certain meaning to the use of the `delegate`, whereas `Func` and `Action` are used for widely disparate purposes.

`Predicate` is mostly used in `List<T>` for methods like `FindAll` and `RemoveAll`.

Comment: You just copied someone else's answer... You could have at lease linked to it or give the author some credit for it...