# Converting a Predicate<T> to a Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with a member `Predicate` which I would like to use in a Linq expression:

```
using System.Linq;

class MyClass
{

    public bool DoAllHaveSomeProperty()
    {
        return m_instrumentList.All(m_filterExpression);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Instrument> m_instrumentList;

    private Predicate<Instrument> m_filterExpression;
}
```

As I read that "`Predicate<T>` is [...] completely equivalent to `Func<T, bool>`" ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110902/1511627)), I would expect this to work, since `All` takes in as argument: `Func<Instrument, bool> predicate`.

However, I get the error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Predicate<MyNamespace.Instrument>' to 'System.Type'
```

Is there a way to convert the predicate to an argument that this function will swallow?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public bool DoAllHaveSomeProperty()
{
    return m_instrumentList.All(i => m_filterExpression(i));
}
```

Comment: Aha, that works, thanks! So Predicate<T> and Func<T,bool> are clearly not **completely** the same, at least not semantically speaking!

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant. :-)

Comment: This has some overhead unfortunately, just fyi. I measured it, it doesn't compile or JIT away.

Answer (score 26):

The two types represent the same logical signature, but that doesn't mean they're just interchangable. A straight assignment won't work, for example - but you can create a new `Func<T, bool>` from the `Predicate<T, bool>`. Sample code:

```
Predicate<string> pred = x => x.Length > 10;
// Func<string, bool> func = pred; // Error
Func<string, bool> func = new Func<string, bool>(pred); // Okay
```

This is a bit like having two `enum` types with the same values - you can convert between them, but you have to do so explicitly. They're still separate types.

In your case, this means you could write:

```
public bool DoAllHaveSomeProperty()
{
    return m_instrumentList.All(new Func<T, bool>(m_filterExpression));
}
```

The lambda expression approach suggested by other answers will work too, of course.

Comment: This `new Func<T, bool>(predicate)` is much much nicer than saying `x => predicate(x)`! Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

You can convert a predicate to a method by calling Invoke.  All delegates have this member.   Delegates don't have structural identity, but methods can be converted to matching delegates.  This fix has a minor performance cost, as it adds an extra layer of indirection.  However, most solutions to this problem have that problem.  Eric Lippert discusses this in more detail at https://web.archive.org/web/20140625132124/http://blog.coverity.com/2014/06/18/delegates-structural-identity/ .

In your specific case, replace `return m_instrumentList.All(m_filterExpression);` with `return m_instrumentList.All(m_filterExpression.Invoke);`

Sample code demonstrating the actual problem.

```
void Main()
{
    Predicate<int> t1 = Foo;
    Func<int,bool> t2 = Foo;
    Predicate<int> t3 = t2.Invoke; //Legal
    Func<int,bool> t4 = t1.Invoke; //Legal
    Predicate<int> t5 = t2; //Illegal
    Func<int,bool> t6 = t1; //Illegal
}

bool Foo(int x)
{
    return x > 20;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
return m_instrumentList.All(i => m_filterExpression(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are a lot of answers i will add one more just for fun.
If you want your code to compile you can use extention methods

```
//Original Code
class MyClass4
{
    public bool DoAllHaveSomeProperty()
    {
        return m_instrumentList.All(m_filterExpression);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Instrument> m_instrumentList;

    private Predicate<Instrument> m_filterExpression;
}
```

Add this class in the same namespace

```
public static class MyExtentions
{
    public static bool All(this IEnumerable<Instrument> enumer, Predicate<Instrument> pred)
    {
        return enumer.All(e => pred(e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Brian said, you can convert a predicate to a method via `Invoke`:

```
public bool DoAllHaveSomeProperty()
{
    return m_instrumentList.All(m_filterExpression.Invoke);
}
```

Comment: So why repeat it?

Comment: @GertArnold Their answer provides a lot of details (which I respect) and the actual solution to the problem looks obstructed. I decided to put a more concise version of the answer so it would be easier to read. Maybe I should have suggested an edit to the existing answer instead.