# Lambda Expression with foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

```
 var coupon=" ";

 foreach(var p in products)
 {
     var query = products.Where(b => b.getId() == p.getId()).ToList();

     if (query != null)
     {
         foreach(var q in query)
         {
             coupon = q.getName();
             Console.WriteLine(coupon);
         }
     }
 }
```

Can anyone tell me what will be the lambda expression of this code-chunk

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. For which part of this code you need an expression? Anyway this question is far too broad, in particlar as you didn´t provide *any* own affords. We´re not here to do your job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every loop operation is a natural fit for a lambda expresssion. Lambda expressions are useful for *projections* of data - i.e. transforming it from one form to another - applying formulae etc, but: that isn't what you're doing here. You're *doing something* with the data (the `Console.WriteLine`. You *could* do something with LINQ here involving `SelectMany`, but... it would become *less* readable, not more.

What you have alread is just fine. The only changes I'd make are:

- to remove the `if (query != null)` test - that is never going to be false
- remove the `ToList()` - there's no need to create a new *list* just to iterate it
- no need to declare `coupon` before it is needed
- I might hoist the `p.getId()`

So:

```
 foreach(var p in products)
 {
     var id = p.getID();
     foreach(var q in products.Where(b => b.getId() == id))
     {
         var coupon = q.getName();
         Console.WriteLine(coupon);
     }
 }
```

Comment: For each product `p`, it writes out the coupon name of all products `q` that share the ID with `p` (including `p` itself). I wonder what ID that is. I agree with your statement _Not every loop operation is a natural fit for a lambda expresssion._ However, if we wanted to create an `IEnumerable<>` of all those coupon names, instead of `Console.WriteLine`, then it might fall under the category of projections of data...

Answer (score 0):

There is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) in your code block and it is the only argument to `Where` and is as follows:

```
b => b.getId() == p.getId()
```

In this particular case, the lambda is *effectively* (though not technically) a [Predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710395/1518546), which is a fancy name for a function that tests if something is `true` or `false`

Comment: Technically, the argument required by `.Select` is a `Func<Product, bool>`, not a `Predicate<Product>` like in .NET-2.0-style methods such as `List<>.FindAll(…)`, however `Func<Product, bool>` and `Predicate<Product>` are equivalent (same signature and return type).

Comment: Good point, I have updated my answer with that clarification.