# Avoid Predicate<object> in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Well I have this C# Code:

```
var searchTerm = search_box.Text;

Predicate<object> firstName = delegate (object pers) 
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Firstname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};

Predicate<object> lastName = delegate (object pers) 
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Lastname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};
```

So the main problem in this Code is that I do not want to use `Predicate`. Is there another possible way to get the same result as the code with `Predicate`

Comment: Couldn't you replace them with functions?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Is it possible with a for loop?

Comment: The more modern way would be `Func<object, bool> firstName = pers => (pers as Person).FirstName.StartsWith(searchTerm);`

Comment: from where do you get the person object anyway

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710301/what-is-a-predicate-in-c

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you don't want to use predicate.  What is your purpose and why is predicate unsuitable for that task?  Once you do that we don't need to guess what you're doing and a specific solution might be best. Maybe chaining linq queries would be a "better" way to go.

Answer (score 3):

To begin, you can simplify version with `Predicate`:

```
Predicate<object> firstName = pers =>
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Firstname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};

Predicate<object> lastName = pers => 
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Lastname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};
```

then you can replace with `Func`:

```
Func<object, bool> firstName = pers =>
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Firstname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};

Func<object, bool> lastName = pers =>
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Lastname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};
```

or use local functions (C# version >= 7.0):

```
bool firstName(object pers) 
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Firstname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};

bool lastName(object pers) 
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Lastname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};
```

or use own `delegate`:

```
public delegate bool SetName(object pers);
//...

SetName firstName = pers => 
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Firstname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};

SetName lastName = pers =>  
{
    var person = pers as Person;
    return person.Lastname.StartsWith(searchTerm); 
};
```

Comment: `delegate (object pers)` can be simplified to `pers =>` as the compiler already knows that the argument is of type object and a lambda (=> notation) here is functionally equivalent to a delegate.

Comment: @ckuri you are absolutely right, I just tried to make minimal changes in this example

Answer (score 0):

You're code seems to be fine, but we can rewrite it like below:

```
var Customer=(Customer)pers ;

Predicate<Customer> predict=x=>
x.Firstname.StartsWith(searchTerm) && x.Lastname.StartsWith(searchTerm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that:

- your question is about [`ICollectionView.Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.filter?view=netcore-3.1)
- and you need to search using both first name and last name
- and `Firstname` and/or `Lastname` can be `null`

your code could be rewritten like this:

```
var searchTerm = search_box.Text;

yourCollectionView.Filter = obj =>
    obj is Person p &&
    (p.Firstname?.StartsWith(searchTerm) == true || 
     p.Lastname?.StartsWith(searchTerm) == true);
```

This, of course, uses `Predicate<object>`, since `Filter` property declared to be `Predicate<object>`, but you don't declare it explicitly.