# c# rewrite complex condition check logic using predicates

Tags: c#, predicate

What is the idea of c# `Predicate` ?
Is it possible to rewrite complex condition check logic using predicates?

```
private bool HasChanged(object originalValue, object currentValue)
{
    if ((originalValue == null && currentValue != null) || 
        (originalValue != null && !originalValue.Equals(currentValue)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Predicate Delegates in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556425/predicate-delegates-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `Predicate<T>` is essentially just a wrapper for `Func<T, bool>` and can be used to encapsulate code that takes a single value and returns a `bool` result. Take a look at [Delegates: Predicate vs. Action vs. Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566860/delegates-predicate-vs-action-vs-func) for more info

Comment: See also [What is a predicate in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710301/what-is-a-predicate-in-c)

Comment: [Predicate<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-2.0) predates, later more generic delegates like [Func<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-3.5) which were introduced with LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

`Predicate<T>` is just a delegate that takes a `T` and returns `bool`. It's the equivalent of `Func<T, bool>` or a method with the signature `bool Method<T>(T input)`.

It doesn't really help you here with your method.

You can, however, simplify your method to this:

```
private bool HasChanged(object originalValue, object currentValue) =>
    originalValue == null
    ? currentValue != null
    : !originalValue.Equals(currentValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bool HasChanged(object originalValue, object currentValue)
    => !(originalValue?.Equals(currentValue) ?? currentValue == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a predicate to check on object agains another object declaring the predicate as an object method. Something like

```
class MyClass
{
    public bool isValid(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is MyClass)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public static class Program
{ 
    static int Main()
    {
        MyClass c1 = new ();

        Predicate<MyClass> predicate = c1.isValid;
        MyClass c2 = new ();
        if (predicate(c2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("c1 is valid");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("c1 is not valid");
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize, that you could simply do `public bool isValid(object obj) => (obj is MyClass);` ?

Comment: Or even slightly better: `public bool IsValid(object obj) => obj is MyClass;`

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this a little by flipping the logic and not attempting to cram it in to a single clause

```
private bool HasChanged(object originalValue, object currentValue)
{
    var bothNull = originalValue == null && currentValue == null;

    if (bothNull){
        return false;
    }

    // at least one of them is not null
    var areSame = originalValue?.Equals(currentValue) ?? false;

    return !areSame;
}
```